# .showAtLocation en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Encontre este tutorial en android el cual permite mostrar un popup window
[ver tutorial](https://gist.github.com/libinbensin/67fcc43a7344758390c3)

Pero lo que yo hago es que se muestre mi popupwindow sin presionar algun boton esto es lo que tengo:

```
private PopupWindow popupWindow;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.conductor);
       View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
       mostrar_popup(rootView);
}

private void mostrar_popup(View rootView) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // inflate the custom popup layout
        final View inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_alumnos, null,false);
        // find the ListView in the popup layout
        ListView lista_alumnos = (ListView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.lista_alumnos);
        // get device size
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        // set height depends on the device size
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x - 50,size.y - 400, true );
        // set a background drawable with rounders corners
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fondo_lista_alumnos));
        // make it focusable to show the keyboard to enter in `EditText`
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        // make it outside touchable to dismiss the popup window
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        // show the popup at bottom of the screen and set some margin at bottom ie,
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,100); //aqui esta mi error
    }
```

conductor.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_conductor"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

de antemano les agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si realizas esto desde onCreate() probablemente tendras un error, ya que no esta creada completamente la vista raíz:

```
   View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
   mostrar_popup(rootView);
```

Para que funcione correctamente llamando el método desde `onCreateView()`, agrega en tu layout cargado mediante `setContentView()` un id, por ejemplo:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:id="@+id/container"

>
```

el id definido es container, entonces llamas el método de esta forma:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        findViewById(R.id.container).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                onShowPopup(rootView);
            }
        });


    }
```

---

De acuerdo a tu còdigo seria de esta forma:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.conductor);


        findViewById(R.id.map_container).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                onShowPopup(rootView);
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: pero lo que deseo hacer es que se llame sin necesidad de hacer click en un boton... es posible hacer eso?

Comment: pero como lo hago eso no tengo entendido, la idea es llamarlo en mi metodo oncreate()

Comment: listo y en este metodo que debe ir?  popWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,100); enves de v

Comment: si hago eso osea dentro del oncreate() tengo setContentView(R.layout v1) y luego hago lo del popup

Comment: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid me sale este error

Comment: voy a aeditar mi pregunta para q as o menos me entienda

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta amigo

Comment: Ahora esta mucho mejor, agrega conductor.xml por favor. @DiegoIsraelMoreno

Comment: listo ya comparto ahora, conductor.xml es una vista que contiene un mapa pero en el metodo mostrar_popup() hago la llamada al popup window similar al del tutorial

Comment: Revisa la actualización y lee lo que comento por favor.

Comment: SIIII ES LA MEJOR RESPUESTA MI AMIGO TE AGRADEZCO MUCHISISISIMO ERES EXCELENTE, RESPUESTA CORRECTA :D

Comment: Un placer ayudarte, saludos Diego!

Comment: Jorgesys popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true); he quitado este metodo para que si toco fuera se cierre el popup, pero igual se quita, Como hago para que sea estatico ese popup? y bueno le agregare un boton para cerrarlo